# Unable to set up keys while installing ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the instructions from here: http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu but in the "set up your keys" step

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
```

i get this:

```
Executing: /tmp/tmp.uIulXAU9Vn/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80
--recv-key
421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116
gpg: requesting key B01FA116 from hkp server ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net
?: ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net: Host not found
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver unreachable
gpg: keyserver communications error: public key not found
gpg: keyserver receive failed: public key not found
```

I searched and found many answers but i think none of them solve this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259269/unable-to-set-up-keys-while-installing-ros-kinetic-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts/) by [moshimojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30028/moshimojo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2017-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe it is because you're behind an http proxy. So other ports aren't working and some http tools are unaware of it.

---

Originally posted by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) with karma: 115 on 2017-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moshimojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30028/moshimojo/) on 2017-04-16**:
I am new to linux. Can you tell me some tips to fix it? Thank you

**Comment by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on 2017-04-16**:
So are you behind a proxy server?

**Comment by [moshimojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30028/moshimojo/) on 2017-04-17**:
i'm sorry for the delay. In the network settings it says i am not.

**Comment by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on 2017-04-17**:
can you try `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key 421C365BD9FF1F717815A3895523BAEEB01FA116` instead?

**Comment by [moshimojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30028/moshimojo/) on 2017-04-17**:
Oh it says "imported". But in the next step `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full`

**Comment by [moshimojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30028/moshimojo/) on 2017-04-17**:
it gives me an error. It says i have held broken packages and non of the packages has been installed

**Comment by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on 2017-04-17**:
did you do `sudo apt-get update` ? Can you update your answer with new info, please?

**Comment by [moshimojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30028/moshimojo/) on 2017-04-17**:
yes i updated. I searched for a same question but i don't see an answer.

**Comment by [moshimojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30028/moshimojo/) on 2017-04-17**:
http://answers.ros.org/question/243920/how-to-install-ros-kinetic-ubuntu-1604/
it's the same

**Comment by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on 2017-04-17**:
Since the key is imported, it seems you have a different problem now and I think it is unrelated to ros. Please, open new question with the exact description of the current problem.

**Comment by [eugene.katsevman](https://answers.ros.org/users/29247/eugene.katsevman/) on 2017-04-17**:
btw, what's your linux distribution ?

**Comment by [moshimojo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30028/moshimojo/) on 2017-04-18**:
Ok thank you! I am using ubuntu 16.04 LTS